# Outer Measure of a Set with a Single Point Removed

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A$ be some subset of $\Bbb{R}$, and $a$ some point in $A$. Prove that $m(A - \{a\}) = m(A)$, where $m(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k) ~|~  A \subseteq \bigcup I_{k=1}^\infty I_k \}$ is the outer measure on $\Bbb{R}$.

Proof: Let $a \in A$ be arbitrary. Since $A - \{a\} \subseteq A$, we know that $m(A \setminus \{a\}) \le m(A)$. Now let $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be some arbitrary cover of $A-\{a\}$, and let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. By adding $(a-\epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ to the cover, we extend it to a cover of $A$. Therefore

$$m(A) \le \ell (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k) = 2 \epsilon + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k).$$

Letting $\epsilon \to 0$, we obtain $m(A) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k)$. Since the cover was arbitrary, this shows that $m(A)$ a lower bound of $\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k) ~|~  A \subseteq \bigcup I_{k=1}^\infty I_k \}$; and so by definition of infimum, we must have $m(A) \le m(A -\{a\})$, which proves the theorem.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Did you mean to say that m(A) is a lower bound of:

$\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell (I_k) ~|~  A-\{a\} \subseteq \bigcup I_{k=1}^\infty I_k \}$.

Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

A shorter argument for $m(A)\leq m(A \setminus \{a\})$:
$$m(A) = m\bigl((A \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{a\}\bigr) \le m(A \setminus \{a\}) + m(\{a\}) = m(A \setminus \{a\})$$ by the subadditivity of the outer measure, and the fact that $m(\{a\}) = 0$, since $\{a\}\subseteq \langle a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon\rangle$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. (Or you can say $m(\{a\}) = \lambda(\{a\}) = 0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.)